# Apache Kafka streaming KTable changelog

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm using Apache Kafka streaming to do aggregation on data consumed from a Kafka topic. The aggregation is then serialized to another topic, itself consumed and results stored in a DB. Pretty classic use-case I suppose.

The result of the aggregate call is creating a KTable backed up by a Kafka changelog "topic".

This is more complex than that in practice, but let's say it is storing the count and sum of events for a given key (to compute average):

```
 KTable<String, Record> countAndSum = groupedByKeyStream.aggregate(...)
```

That changelog "topic" does not seem to have a retention period set (I don't see it "expires" on the contrary of the other topics per my global retention setting).

This is actually good/necessary because this avoids losing my aggregation state when a future event comes with the same key.

However on the long run this means this changelog will grow forever (as more keys get in)? And I do potentially have a lot of keys (and my aggregation are not as small as count/sum).

As I have a means to know that I won't get anymore events of a particular key (some events are marked as "final"), is there a way for me to strip the aggregation states for these particular keys of the changelog to avoid having it grows forever as I won't need them anymore, possibly with a slight delay "just" in case?

Or maybe there is a way to do this entirely differently with Kafka streaming to avoid this "issue"?

Comment: I've just read about tombstone messages, key will a null message that might allow me to drop those. Still need to test. And still interested in what would be the correct pattern anyway.

Comment: Yes: changelog topics are configured with log compaction and not with retention time. If you receive the "final" record, your aggregation can just return `null` as aggregation result. This will delete it from the local RocksDB store as well as the underlying changelog topic.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I have tested and confirm all goes as expected with returning null when reaching the "final" record.

Comment: Posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: changelog topics are configured with log compaction and not with retention time. If you receive the "final" record, your aggregation can just return `null` as aggregation result. This will delete it from the local RocksDB store as well as the underlying changelog topic.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I have looked for this in Kafka documentation but still didn't find an explicit statement like this one. Is there any official doc link about this ?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for exactly, but it might not be documented. -- Maybe worth to do a PR to add it to the docs (would you be interested to help on this)?

Comment: Sure ! In this [link](https://kafka.apache.org/35/documentation/streams/architecture#streams_architecture_recovery) we say "Log compaction is enabled on the changelog topics so that old data can be purged safely to prevent the topics from growing indefinitely." I think the statement would not be correct if we have a huge key space (not sure if it's a rare case). I wonder if I can suggest a change specifying that's it's only compact and not delete policy ?

Comment: I see the confusion. "old data" here really means, "old versions for the same key", ie,  everything but the current version for a key... Also "huge key space" does not really matter as long as it's a _bounded_ (and stable) key space -- of course, if your key space changes, old keys sit there forever. -- If you want to propose an update to the docs, just open a PR on the AK GitHub repository and we can take it from there.